# JSON: schedule creation of json file

Tags: wp-query, json

After some research I've managed to create a json file which I use as input for Twitter's typeahead (prefetch). On my website I have several hundreds of events and several thousands of artists (both custom post types).

The json files are created using the function below (only posted one function since the function for artists is the same except it's a different post type). Since we keep updating the events and artists, and since we have so much of both, I was wondering how I should go about running the functions. My idea was to schedule this function, so it will run once every day or so. After some more research I should be able to fix this (using [this post](http://wpmu.org/schedule-functions-in-your-plugins-with-wordpress-cron/)).

Now my question is if this is good practice. I thought it would be great to schedule the functions to run every night (we have over 8000 artists so I don't want the functions to slow down the website for visitors), but maybe there's another efficient way of building such large datasets.

The function:

```
function json_events() {

  $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  );

  $query = new WP_Query($args);

  $json = array();

  while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
    $json[] = get_the_title();
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();

  $fp = fopen('events.json', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, json_encode($json));
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My idea was to schedule this function, so it will run once every day
>   or so. After some more research I should be able to fix this (using
>   this post).

Note that `WP_Cron` setted to *daily* is impossible to control `exactly` at what time the creation happen. If no one visit your site on night the first user on morning will experience a very long page loading time.
There are some workaround, sometimes I've used one: create a function that hook into `shutdown` action and then, from that function call the url that run the *heavy work* via `curl`.

However, if you have access to the [cron table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is better use this feature.

Also because search engines will trigger the `WP_Cron` too, so there are chances that the slow work start on search engine visit, resulting in slow page loading that will affect SEO.

> .. but maybe there's another efficient way of building such large
>   datasets.

If you need to refresh **all** the file content every day there are little chances. But if **all** your artists/events CPT post titles don't change every day, you can

1. Run the file creation once
2. hooking into `save_post`, `post_updated` and `delete_post` and when a new artist or event is added, **increment the prefetch file** (i.e. just append the new title instead of build entire file) with the new title. When a title is updated or a post is deleted (or restored from trash) recreate the file again

In this way you **don't** need to run any heavy scheduled task, and no website slow down will occur.

I've written a simple plugin that do the incremental saving stuff. The plugin saves json files in the WP `uploads` directory under a `/json` subfolder.

```
<?php 
/**
 * Plugin Name: Json Posts Incremental
 * http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113198/json-schedule-creation-of-json-file
 * Author: G. M.
 * Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/35541/
 */

class Json_Posts_Incremental {

  static $types = array('artists', 'events');

  static $path;

  static $url;

  static function init() {
    self::set_path();
    add_action('admin_init', array( __CLASS__, 'build_all') );
    add_action('delete_post', array( __CLASS__, 'update'), 20, 1 );
    add_action('post_updated', array( __CLASS__, 'update'), 20, 3 );
  }

  static function build_all() {
    foreach ( self::$types as $type ) self::build($type, false);
  }

  static function update( $post_ID = 0, $post_after = null, $post_before = null) {
    if ( ! empty($post_after) && ! empty($post_before) ) {
      $new = $post_before->post_status == 'auto-draft' || $post_before->post_status == 'new';
      if ( $new ) return self::increment($post_ID, $post_after, false);
      $skip = $post_after->post_status != 'publish' && $post_before->post_status != 'publish';
      if ( $skip ) return;
      $trash = ( $post_after->post_status == 'trash' && $post_before->post_status == 'publish' ) || // trash
        ( $post_after->post_status == 'publish' && $post_before->post_status == 'trash' ); // restore
      if ( ! $trash && ( $post_after->post_title == $post_before->post_title ) ) return;
    } else {
      $post_after = get_post($post_ID);
      if ( ! is_object($post_after) || ! isset($post_after->post_type) || $post_after->post_status == 'trash' ) return;
    }
    if ( in_array($post_after->post_type, self::$types) ) self::build( $post_after->post_type, true );
  }

  static function increment( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    if ( $update || ! in_array($post->post_type, self::$types) ) return;
    $file = trailingslashit(self::$path) . $post->post_type . '.json';
    $content = file_exists($file) ? file_get_contents($file) : '[]';
    $content = rtrim($content, ']');
    if ( $content != '[') $content .= ',';
    $content .= json_encode($post->post_title) . ']';
    self::write($file, $content);
  }

  static function get_json( $type ) {
    $file = trailingslashit(self::$path) . $type . '.json';
    return ( file_exists($file) ) ? file_get_contents($file) : '';
  }

  static function get_json_file( $type ) {
    $file = trailingslashit(self::$path) . $type . '.json';
    return ( file_exists($file) ) ? $file : '';
  }

  static function get_json_url( $type ) {
    $file = trailingslashit(self::$path) . $type . '.json';
    return ( file_exists($file) ) ? trailingslashit(self::$url) . $type . '.json' : '';
  }   

  private static function build( $type = '', $force = false ) {
    if ( ! in_array($type, self::$types) ) return;
    $file = trailingslashit(self::$path) . $type . '.json';
    if ( file_exists($file) && ! $force ) return;
    $titles = array();
    $posts = get_posts("post_type=$type&nopaging=1");
    if ( ! empty($posts) ) {
      foreach ( $posts as $post )
        $titles[] = apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title);
      $content = json_encode( $titles );
      self::write($file, $content);
    }
  }

  private static function set_path() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    self::$path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/json';
    self::$url = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/json';
    if ( ! file_exists(self::$path) ) mkdir(self::$path, 0775);
  }

  private static function write( $file = '', $content = '' ) {
    $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);
  }

}

add_action('init', array('Json_Posts_Incremental', 'init') );
```

To retrieve the json file url, e.g. to pass it to js you can use `Json_Posts_Incremental::get_json_url($type)` where `$type` is the post type e.g. `events`.

Others utility functions are:

`Json_Posts_Incremental::get_json_file($type)` to retrieve the file path.

`Json_Posts_Incremental::get_json($type)` to retrieve the json content as string.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! That's really helpful. Do I need to use this as a regular plugin? Or can I just put this in a php file and include that in functions.php?

Comment: Just one more question. I just noticed I've posted an older version of my function. Later on I've put `$json[] = html_entity_decode(get_the_title());` instead of `$json[] = get_the_title();` because else the special characters would display as ASCII code in the search field. In your code, where do I put the `html_entity_decode`? I guess in the `foreach` loop? After `apply_filters`?

Comment: @joostvanhoof **1)** the file can be a plugin or in functions.php, it's the same. If you don't want lost feature on theme switch use it as a plugin, code it's ready for that, just copy in plugin folder and activate. **2)** in `increment` function replace `$content .= json_encode($post->post_title) . ']';` with `$content .= json_encode( html_entity_decode($post->post_title) ) . ']';` in `build` function replace `$titles[] = apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title);` with `$titles[] = apply_filters('the_title', html_entity_decode($post->post_title) );`

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought everything was working (and it was...) but now it seems that html_entity_decode doesn't work anymore. I'm kind of stuck between two problems; I don't know if the generation of the json file or typeahead.js creates the problem. See my typeahead.js post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702542/typeahead-prefetch-weird-behaviour.

Comment: @joostvanhoof I don't know twitter typeahead enought to see if your code is right. But maybe you have to format the json as an array of object, not as an array of strings. See [typeahead docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#datum)

Comment: Hi GM. It seems that there's a problem at the point where the json file gets stored in the local storage. I'm not really experienced in this stuff. If you have any knowledge on this topic, I would appreciate it if you can take a look. I've opened a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718635/json-to-itemhash-gets-cut-off). I think that if I can fix this problem, the `html_entity_decode` problem will also be solved. Anyway, thanks for your fantastic help!

Comment: Sorry, @joostvanhoof my knowledge in this field are not enough to understand your problem..

Comment: The problem seems to be two fold. One part is that the newly added custom post types are added at the END of the json file. Even when I empty my local storage, the CPTs added at the end are not recognized by typeahead. Only when I delete the json file so it's recreated, and then add another item, all newly added items move to the start of the document and then the typeahead works. So in that case the json file seems to be the problem. Is there a way to append newly added items to the beginning of the document instead of the end?

Comment: Finally found the error. Removed `apply_filters` from `$titles[] = apply_filters('the_title',html_entity_decode($post->post_title));`. Now `html_entity_decode` is working! This doesn't affect the plugin right? Thanks again!