# Create and Update a Json file

Tags: json

I have been tried merge two piece of code, but I'm not a developer. It's a little hard for me =(

I need build an auto update .json file with some custom fields for a personal project.

I have this code that make the json that I need.

```
    $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    //'nopaging' => true 
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); // $query is the WP_Query Object
$posts = $query->get_posts();   // $posts contains the post objects

$output = array();
foreach( $posts as $post ) {    // Pluck the id and title attributes
        $id = get_the_id();
        $name = get_the_title();
        $city = get_field('space-city');
        $country = get_field('space-contry');
        $photo = get_field('space-photo');
        $desc = get_field('space-description');
        $local = get_field('space-map');
        // image        
        $photoField = get_field('space-photo');
        $photoUrl = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $photoField, 'photo-card' );


    $output[] = array( 
        'id' => $id,
        'title' => $name,
        'city' => $city,
        'country' => $country,
        'address' => $local['address']
);}

echo json_encode( $output );
```

And I have this other code for create and update the final file ([from here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113198/json-schedule-creation-of-json-file)).

```
  class Json_Posts_Incremental {

  static $types = array('post');

  static $path;

  static $url;

  static function init() {
    self::set_path();
    add_action('admin_init', array( __CLASS__, 'build_all') );
    add_action('delete_post', array( __CLASS__, 'update'), 20, 1 );
    add_action('post_updated', array( __CLASS__, 'update'), 20, 3 );
  }

  static function build_all() {
    foreach ( self::$types as $type ) self::build($type, false);
  }

  static function update( $post_ID = 0, $post_after = null, $post_before = null) {
    if ( ! empty($post_after) && ! empty($post_before) ) {
      $new = $post_before->post_status == 'auto-draft' || $post_before->post_status == 'new';
      if ( $new ) return self::increment($post_ID, $post_after, false);
      $skip = $post_after->post_status != 'publish' && $post_before->post_status != 'publish';
      if ( $skip ) return;
      $trash = ( $post_after->post_status == 'trash' && $post_before->post_status == 'publish' ) || // trash
        ( $post_after->post_status == 'publish' && $post_before->post_status == 'trash' ); // restore
      if ( ! $trash && ( $post_after->post_title == $post_before->post_title ) ) return;
    } else {
      $post_after = get_post($post_ID);
      if ( ! is_object($post_after) || ! isset($post_after->post_type) || $post_after->post_status == 'trash' ) return;
    }
    if ( in_array($post_after->post_type, self::$types) ) self::build( $post_after->post_type, true );
  }

  static function increment( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    if ( $update || ! in_array($post->post_type, self::$types) ) return;
    $file = trailingslashit(self::$path) . $post->post_type . '.json';
    $content = file_exists($file) ? file_get_contents($file) : '[]';
    $content = rtrim($content, ']');
    if ( $content != '[') $content .= ',';
    $content .= json_encode($post->post_title) . ']';
    self::write($file, $content);
  }

  static function get_json( $type ) {
    $file = trailingslashit(self::$path) . $type . '.json';
    return ( file_exists($file) ) ? file_get_contents($file) : '';
  }

  static function get_json_file( $type ) {
    $file = trailingslashit(self::$path) . $type . '.json';
    return ( file_exists($file) ) ? $file : '';
  }

  static function get_json_url( $type ) {
    $file = trailingslashit(self::$path) . $type . '.json';
    return ( file_exists($file) ) ? trailingslashit(self::$url) . $type . '.json' : '';
  }   

  private static function build( $type = '', $force = false ) {
    if ( ! in_array($type, self::$types) ) return;
    $file = trailingslashit(self::$path) . $type . '.json';
    if ( file_exists($file) && ! $force ) return;
    $titles = array();
    $posts = get_posts("post_type=$type&nopaging=1");
    if ( ! empty($posts) ) {
      foreach ( $posts as $post )
        $titles[] = apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title);
      $content = json_encode( $titles );
      self::write($file, $content);
    }
  }

  private static function set_path() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    self::$path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/json';
    self::$url = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/json';
    if ( ! file_exists(self::$path) ) mkdir(self::$path, 0775);
  }

  private static function write( $file = '', $content = '' ) {
    $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);
  }

}

add_action('init', array('Json_Posts_Incremental', 'init') );
```

How can I merge it? Where I need put my part of the code in the second code?

Thank you